# Midpoint of $O_1O_2$ coincides with the center of a circumcircle

Tags: geometry, circles

Two circles $O_1$ and $O_2$ intersect at $A$ and $B$. Through $A$ a line cuts $O_ 1$ at $C$ and $O_2$ at $D$. Denote $M$ is the midpoint of $CD$.

Prove that the center of circumcircle of triangle $ABM$ bisects $O_1O_2$.[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Could you present a figure? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I see you haven't validated the answers you have received even a very long time ago. You have to do it (if the answer is good of course). Think that people who have answered have spend time for you. This is the way such a site works well.

Comment: what do mean by validating the answers?

Comment: Validating an answer is done by clicking on the "check" sign in the margin (looking like a square root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary : Let $O$ be defined as the midpoint of $O_1O_2$.

Let us reformulate the question into the more natural one :

**Prove that $M$ belongs to the circle $(C')$ with center $O$ and radius $OA$.**

This issue can be treated by 2 methods 1) and 2) :

1) **a 3D understanding method** : Consider the 2 figures :

[image]

[image]

The first one looks very similar (at least for a part of the line segments) to the initial figure. The second one is a 3D "expansion " of the first figure where these line segments become generating lines of a [one sheeted hyperboloid] (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-SheetedHyperboloid.html) intersected by a horizontal plane at half distance between the bottom and the top circles.

**2) Using powers of points with respect to circles**. The set of points such that the sum of powers of $M$ with respect to  $(C_1)$ and $(C_2)$ is equal to $k$ is a circle (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594844)). It is not difficult to see that circle $(C')$ is the circle of this family associated with constant $k=0$.

Comment: Respect to method 1), I don't see the homothey H has a center at A. I thought the homothety center is the intersection of two tangent line. In your homothety, how is O1 mapped to O2.  Do you have link to your statement?    Respect to method 2), do you mean the power of point having a sign? It seems odd to me.   I find a article of this midcircle theorem proof in French: http://jl.ayme.pagesperso-orange.fr/Docs/midcircle%20theorem.pdf

Comment: I see your second method: power of point is defined as d^2- r^2. Your link is good. Thanks!

Comment: For method 1 : You are right. I correct it at once.

Comment: In French, what does it mean by  monienne in "(CJA) est une monienne de 3 et 1 si, et seulement si, 3 passe par P". The french article is amazing.

Comment: I didn't know this term : it is given to any straight line passing through one of the points of intersection of 2 circles (http://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./m/monienne.html)

Comment: Yes this document if full of things that are not known or ill-known.

Comment: I suppress the first part, in order to re-write it properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It has really been helpful. I also notice some homothety from B (intersection of two circles): from B, send O1, O2 and O to S, T and N by factor of 2. Because O1, O2 and O are colinear, so are S, T and N. But S on O1, T on O2 and N is the midpoint of ST. So N is on midcircle. BN will be the diameter.

Comment: Look at my (new) solution (the first one was truly erroneous, sorry for that ; neverthelss, I think that there exists a proof with transformation geometry).

Comment: HI Jean, Thanks, It is really amazing.